# How to solve problem in master page in C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have html code and want to split it between `site.master` and `default.aspx`

When I put a full code on site.master it works, but when I took a part of code and put it in `default.aspx`, it doesn't work!

I just want to know how to make `default.aspx` reach all classes in .css files

This is my tag which cant take a class from .css

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationClinicASP._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

      <section class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-image: url('images/bg_3.jpg');" data-section="home" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-start" data-scrollax-parent="true">
          <div class="col-md-6 pt-5 ftco-animate">
            <div class="mt-5">
                <span class="subheading">Welcome to Mediplus</span>
                <h1 class="mb-4">We are here <br>for your Care</h1>
                <p class="mb-4">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">Make an appointment</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Clearly explain what goes wrong, and provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: doesnt take a design from .css files ..

Comment: So? Did you add a reference to the .css file somewhere? Provide a [mcve] demonstrating that. Did you make sure the .css file loaded in the browser's network tools? Make sure that you're not using a cached version? Make sure you're running the correct version of the app that includes the changes?

Comment: all of this suggestions already done :(

Comment: You need to add more details, or we won't be able to help. For example, the page source in the browser and the CSS rule that isn't being applied.

Comment: what details u want to know ?

Comment: We've already specified what we need from you. If you fail to provide that detail, we can't help you.